# Sencha Touch Horizontal Bar Chart in accordion not rendering in Chrome but is rendered on Firefox

Tags: extjs, touch, accordion, bar-chart

Sencha Touch Horizontal Bar Chart in accordion not rendering in Chrome but is rendered on Firefox.there is no error on the logs.Have checked if its a Chrome 29 bug issue, its not.Request your help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, I create a charts on the server by other tools and write it to response as an image. Image is absolutely cross browser :) My favorite chart is Devexpress XtraChart